# access count number of records with criteria celebrity

Tags: mysql, sql

i was looking for a solution for my problem for along time, i wish you help me 
i have a table with a two column first is a name and two is a town i need to count Sarah from Egpyt how many it repeated but here is the trick i need the result like table 2 below is it possible

```
Name    town
Sarah   Egypt
John    Germany
Mick    France
Sarah   Egypt
Sarah   USA
John    Germany
Mick    France
John    Germany

Name    town    duplicate
Sarah   Egypt      1
John    Germany    1
Mick    France     1
Sarah   Egypt      2
Sarah   USA        1
John    Germany    2
Mick    France     2
John    Germany    3
```

Comment: Can you provide your table complete definition. Is there any primary key defined for this table

Comment: Last line of your output `John    Germany    3`, how is this possible?

Comment: there is no a primary key because the date could be duplicated

Comment: i modified the table thank you for your notice

Comment: @AhmedKamal can you post the updated table definition along with the data ?

Comment: @AhmedKamal - You can check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the aggregation function count(*) and group by

```
select name, town, count(*) as duplicated 
from my_table 
group by  name, town
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**Create Table:**

```
create table test (name varchar(20), town varchar(20));
```

**Insert Statement:**

```
insert into test value('Sarah','Egypt');
insert into test values('John','Germany');
insert into test values('Mick','France');
insert into test values('Sarah','Egypt');
insert into test values('Sarah','USA');
insert into test values('John','Germany');
insert into test values('Mick','France');
insert into test values('Sarah','Egypt');
```

**Query:**

```
set @x=1;
set @checkname='';
set @checktown='';
select name, town ,row_number
from ( select name, town, if(@checkname = name && @checktown = town,@x := @x + 1 ,@x := 1) as row_number,
@checkname := name, @checktown := town
from test
order by name, town 
) a
```

Comment: @AhmedKamal Have you tested above query ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query :

```
SET @row_number:=1;
SET @name:='';
SET @town:='';
    SELECT @row_number:=CASE WHEN @name=name and @town=town THEN @row_number+1 
      ELSE 1 END AS row_number, @name:=name, @town:=town
    FROM Table1 order by name, town;
```

Check [SQL HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b58b1/3)